# How to profile a concurrent Java code

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am practicing concurrent java and wrote a concurrent mergesort. The Mergesort is working well if the number of elements are less than 10,000. However, more than that it seems to take forever, I believe that the some of the threads are stuck(deadlock?). Now I don't have any shared resource as I always pass and return new copy. What are some known ways to profile such code for e.g. which threads are stuck, how many threads have been executed?

Sharing the code for reference:-

```
package mergesort;

import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

// 18s
public class Main {
  public static final ExecutorService ex = new ThreadPoolExecutor(100, 100, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
      new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10000), new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    int n = 1_000_000;
    Future<int[]> T1 = ex.submit(new Callable<int[]>() {

      @Override
      public int[] call() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mergesort(generate(n));
      }
    });

    int[] ret = T1.get();
    for (int i : ret) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
    System.out.println("done");
    ex.shutdownNow();
  }

  public static int[] generate(int n) {
    int[] nums = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      nums[i] = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
    }
    return nums;
  }

  public static int[] mergesort(int[] nums) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    final int[] B;
    if (nums.length < 2) {
      return nums;
    }
    final int[] A = new int[nums.length / 2];
    if (nums.length % 2 == 0) {
      B = new int[nums.length / 2];
    } else {
      B = new int[nums.length / 2 + 1];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      if (i < nums.length / 2) {
        A[i] = nums[i];
      } else {
        B[i - nums.length / 2] = nums[i];
      }
    }

    Future<int[]> T2 = ex.submit(new Callable<int[]>() {

      @Override
      public int[] call() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mergesort(B);
      }
    });
    Future<int[]> T1 = ex.submit(new Callable<int[]>() {

      @Override
      public int[] call() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mergesort(A);
      }
    });
    Future<int[]> T3 = ex.submit(new Callable<int[]>() {
      @Override
      public int[] call() throws Exception {

        return merge(T1.get(), T2.get());
      }
    });
    return T3.get();
  }

  public static int[] merge(int[] A, int[] B) {
    int[] ret = new int[A.length + B.length];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    while (i < A.length && j < B.length) {
      if (A[i] < B[j]) {
        ret[k] = A[i];
        i++;
      } else {
        ret[k] = B[j];
        j++;
      }
      k++;
    }

    while (j < B.length) {
      ret[k] = B[j];
      j++;
      k++;
    }
    while (i < A.length) {
      ret[k] = A[i];
      i++;
      k++;
    }
    return ret;
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

So using the tools I could analyze memory dump, see the running threads, live objects etc. But what are the strategies people follow(things they look for) when trying to understand the stack trace of a concurrent process. I.e. where do I start looking? for e.g. in my example I saw that all my tasks are waiting on FutureTask, but that's it. Why FutureTask is not returning I have no idea. How can I move further?

Comment: JDK tools: Jconsole? JMC?

Comment: Thanks, Tried using JConsole, have a follow up question in the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you create `Future`s recursively, then a huge number of threads are necessary to compute intermediate results and the pool may not have sufficient number of available threads. Mind that most of your threads are blocked waiting for others to give their results, so when the pool is exhausted you have: threads waiting for new threads to be created (while it is impossible due to pool exhaustion).

If you use a cached thread pool, it will work:

```
ExecutorService ex = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

as such a pool is expandable.

----- EDIT -----

I also recommend you to use the new Java 8 functional style:

```
Future<int[]> f2 = ex.submit(() -> mergesort(B));
Future<int[]> f1 = ex.submit(() -> mergesort(A));
return merge(f1.get(),f2.get());
```

Also note, that it is not useful to use a `Future` to compute the merge as you are synchronizing on it.

Comment: Ah, so all the tasks splitting the array takes up the available pooled threads, so merge step never happens...

Comment: Exactly, that's it

Comment: newCachedThreadPool() as I understand, creates new threads as required. I used it, and got OOM within 1 seconds(I have 6 GB max heap size). Could it be possible that each of thread is actually having their local copy of array, making the tasks quite heavyweight?

Comment: Yes. Mergesort can be implemented in-place, I recommended it especially if you have huge volume of data...

Comment: Made the change to make only merge step concurrent. Still try to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some of the profiler available in the market like [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/%20youkit) or [AppDynamics](https://www.appdynamics.com/%20Appdynamics) . You can use trial version of both. or you can simply take the thread dump and analyze yourself but it will be time-consuming.

I preferred App-dynamics , i was having very big application and using the thread-dump and analyze it manually was very time-consuming.

Refer https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO14S/Trace+MultiThreaded+Transactions+for+Java , on how to trace multi-threaded app using App-dynamics.

App-dynamics also shows that which piece of code is causing the thread-contention, how much time thread is running/blocking. Also it shows whether its a CPU which is getting bottleneck or thread is waiting on some shared resource etc.

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Thanks appdynamics looks interesting. I will spend some time on it,

Comment: sure , i am sure you will like it :)